# COMException results in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, com

I'm using a proprietary chemical simulation package called "Aspen Custom Modeler." (ACM)  ACM natiely has a COM interface you can use to drive it.  AspenTech expects one to use Visual Basic to interact with ACM, but I, not liking VB very much, went with C#.  This has caused me all manner of trouble.

My newest issue is that ACM will throw an exceptions for even simple errors that can arise in normal usage.  I have a data set that fails to converge.  ACM throws a COMException, STS_F_Failure.  In Visual Basic I get the correct type, but in C#, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception for some reason.

My guess is that the Interop library does not have the correct exception types.  Does anyone know a way I can get the correct types for exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

The CLR will do it's best to make COM objects look like .Net objects especially with respect to exceptions.  It will examine the specific `HRESULT` value, consult information like `IErrorInfo`, etc ... in order to determine the *best* .Net way to represent the failure.

In this case it's appearing to choose a `NullReferenceException` which means that it's very likely the method is returning a value that looks like `E_POINTER`.

Controlling this is difficult at best.  The only real option you have is to generate the .Net library such that it uses `HRESULT` returns and not exceptions.  If that's not possible, or simply not paletable, then I would advise simply catching the `NullReferenceException` here.

This article has a nice explanation of how this mapping occurs

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx

Comment: It does not seem that the HRESULT matches any code that corresponds to a NullPointer. The HRESULT is 189, for which Errlook returns "The operating system cannot run %1."  Furthermore, I have also gotten the same NullPointer exception for exceptions from other functions in the same library I'm pretty sure are not of the same type.

Comment: tlbimp, unfortunately, does not seem to generate anything like a good interface for ACM.  (Compile-time binding is totally broken with it.)  So using tlbimp to generate a new interop library did not help.  I doubt writing my own is a good idea, since I don't know anything about the interface really. (It's proprietary.)  So, I guess I'm stuck with catching the exception and pretending I know what it is.